# jq negative select elements of array

Tags: arrays, json, jq, regex-negation

Take the data set as lines of arrays with values, e.g.:

[ "Dog", "cat", "Bird"]

I would like to get an array with all those values that do not match a regex but am unwilling to use negative capture groups (regex is more complicated than that) - so if my criteria would be that first letter must be capital, the output array should be ["cat"]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> all those values that do not match a regex

Sounds like `test(_) | not` is what you're looking for. Assuming you meant to write "first letter must NOT be a capital", the following filter could be used:

```
map(select(test("^[A-Z]")|not))
```

Comment: But then the output is just true/false rather than the value tested

Comment: Surely you jest.  Or maybe you misplaced a parenthesis?

Comment: he was refering to a *filter*, that is then popped into the correct select

Comment: @Hvisage - In jq, all “functions” are filters.